# Running two cmd commands in one go?

Tags: autohotkey

```
cd "C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\"
```

followed by

```
dopusrt.exe /info documents\filelist1.txt,listsel,0
```

Attempting to run it like so;

```
2::
Run, %comspec% /k cd "C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\" && %ComSpec% /k dopusrt.exe /info documents\filelist1.txt,listsel,0,, Hide
Return
```

```
Gives me an error. ==> The following variable name contains an illegal character: ", Hide"
```

It thinks, the commas in the second CMD command are AHK parameters.

I've tried quoting the second command in its entirety but the CMD window seem to only receive the first command.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commas indeed are one problem, another problem is your usage of `%comspec% /k`.
Right now, what you're trying to, is use the `Run`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)</sup> command, where the parameters would be as follows:

- **`Target`** = `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k cd "C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\" && C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k dopusrt.exe /info documents\filelist1.txt`
- **`WorkingDir`** = `listsel`
- **`Options`** = `0`
- **`OutputVarPID`** = `, Hide`

The `comspec`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#ComSpec)</sup> variable contains the path to cmd.exe and the `/k` switch<sup>[(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd#parameters)</sup> means to run the specified command.
So, you of course don't want to specify these things twice. Just one at the start of the command. (`Run` a program (cmd.exe) with the specified parameters (`/k`, `cd`,  `"C:\Program Files\...`))

And about the commas, in legacy syntax (you're writing legacy syntax here) you'll need to escape<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm)</sup> them with `` `, ``.

So in legacy syntax your finished command would look like this:

```
Run, %ComSpec% /k cd "C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\" && dopusrt.exe /info documents\filelist1.txt`,listsel`,0, , Hide
```

And in modern expression syntax it'd look like this:

```
Run, % A_ComSpec " /k cd ""C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\"" && dopusrt.exe /info documents\filelist1.txt,listsel,0", , Hide
```

I'd recommend ditching the legacy syntax and starting to just write expression syntax.
[Here's](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm) a documentation page to get you started about the differenced between legacy syntax and expression syntax, if you're interested.

---

But really, this whole approach with `cd`ing to the directory where `dopusrt.exe` is seems really silly to me. Not seeing the point of it.
Should be fine to just run the `dopusrt.exe` program directly?

```
Run, % """C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\dopusrt.exe"" /info documents\filelist1.txt,listsel,0", , Hide
```

Comment: Who are you?!! Quite possibly the most succinct explanation I have ever gotten.  I am relatively new to all of this, so I am just winging it. Allot of people mentioned legacy and expression syntax but did not really grasp it but I finally get it now. Your explanation of `%comspec%` helped understand  so much. No more `CD` into places anymore. Thank you!